# Facebook login button doesn't appear in firefox?

Tags: asp.net, facebook

The problem is that if you get in there 
http://d4403897.u95.gohsphere.com/login.aspx 
with google chrome the Facebook login button will apear , but if you get in with firefox it will dissapear !? 
The Code to show this button is

```
     <div id="fb-root"></div>
     <div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>
```

Comment: Problem Resolved , the issue was with the place for the declaration for the javascript code it have to be above the Div , and it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try just `<div class="fb-login-button"/>` and see if it works. Then add each parameter and try it. I just tested your code in my firefox, and works with no problem.

Comment: the login button appeared ?

Comment: I mean, I put it in a new php with all facebook stuff and works. Indeed, your site misses it on firefox. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Maybe more of your code may light things up a bit more

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, the button didn't show up in firefox.

The solution for me was that I have deleted all the history.